# 2T2R with two antennas

Tags: antenna, mimo

Regarding the 2T2R, the device should have two transmitter antennas and two receiver antennas in order to double the data rate. However, as I see different devices, the 2T2R has only two antennas, and 4T4R has four antennas. As I know, most of these devices support full duplex. Why do they have half of the antennas on their board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each antenna is both a transmit and receive antenna, so you can run 2T2R with only two antennas...

Comment: Thank you, Paul for your answer, So for sending two data at the same time, both antennas are in sending mode, and the receiver parts don't receive anything. it means by using two antennas to improve the data rate we lose the full duplex ability.

Comment: No, each antenna can actually receive and transmit at the same time, due to some magic that separates the transmitted signal from the received signal (usually a circulator, like here: https://www.analog.com/-/media/analog/en/landing-pages/technical-articles/5g-tech-devices-for-an-o-ran-wireless-solution/353722-fig-01.jpg?w=900&imgver=1 which shows a 4T4R)